# Encog mean value with one input and one output

Tags: neural-network, encog

I want to build a neural network with Encog that have 1 input (0/1 or true/false) and 1 ouput (double value) that calculates a mean value if criteria was specified (1 as an input) and 0 if criteria wasn't specified (0 as an input).

For example, if I have the following training dataset

```
input | ideal
  1   |  0.6
  0   |  0
  1   |  0.2
  1   |  0.4
```

Then I expect something around ~**0.0** if input was 0 and ~**0.4** if input was 1.

I have simplified my problem a lot. But the 2 principal questions are:

1. Can I go with such dataset or should I calculate average for all
   duplicating input values and start a network training with unique
   inputs?
2. What is the best network structure (network type,
   activation function, propagation) for the problem described above?

Comment: Let's say as input you have 1, and as output you want to get 6? Am I correct?

Comment: No, I want a value that is close to the average value of all ideal outputs for the input 1. For the training set above it will be 0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make averager from neural network, but you need to modify your training set. For now you have three ones, and only one zero which means that your NN will add some kind of bias. Or if bias is something, that you like you just need to train your NN. With regard to network structure I recommend you multilayer neural network with sigmoidal function and with backpropogation as training method, or you can try quickprop also.